# Add text substitution for all words ending with certain letters

Tags: text, spelling

I’d like to have automatic spelling correction in MAC OSX 10.7 for all words ending with certain letter sequences. It would help me a lot in my typing if all words ending with "...ao” were substituted by “ão”, for example.

Is it possible, or do I really have to add every word in Text and Language —> Text menu?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably a text-replacement suite that supports [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  They can be cryptic at first but once you learn the syntax, they are extremely powerful.

There was a [previous question on another site](https://superuser.com/questions/115348/mac-os-x-search-and-replace-tool-with-regular-expression-support) that netted a product called [Find and Replace It](http://www.dprog.ch/home/products/find_and_replace_it/) which looks appropriate for your usage.